# Crosstalk between transmission lines

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, physics, interference, crosstalk

I was reading [these slides](https://slideplayer.com/slide/5041632/) about crosstalk between transmission lines. At page 6 there is this circuital model to describe the effect of mutual coupling between these two lines:

[image]

My doubt is: why \$I_{Cm}\$ goes in both directions while \$I_{Lm}\$ not? And what is the definitions of both directions? They seems equivalent for me (look for instance at the line at right: it is identical in both directions, since it is in both cases loaded with an impedance equal to \$Z_0\$).

Comment: The current in the right-hand case is due to inductive coupling and does NOT flow FROM one transmission line to the other like your green arrow shows. Current flowing toward Z0 in the 1st transmission line (pink arrow) will induce an EMF in the 2nd transmission line that willl produce current flow the opposite direction. This is Faraday's law emf = -dλ/dt. That resulting current in the 2nd transmission line produces a magnetic field that tends to oppose the field that created it. The green arrowhead is pointing the correct way, but the tail should not be coming from the 1st trans line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of capacitive coupling, the mechanism is the change in an electric field perpendicular to the conductors, so there's no reason the resulting current would not flow in both directions.

In the case of inductive coupling, the mechanism is the *change* in a magnetic field *wrapping around* the conductors.   The direction of wrapping of a magnetic field depends on the source current via the right hand rule, and the direction of current induced by a change in a magnetic field is forced by Lenz's law to be in the direction opposing the change in field.

Or to put another way, because when you apply Maxwell's equations to the situation and reduce, that's what the math says.

It might help if you thought of the first situation as if there were a tiny off-the-shelf capacitor between the lines.  And the second as if they were wound through a small transformer core.